# Why my data is overfitting despite my usage of cross validation with cross_val_score in logistic regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am using “WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv” file on Telcom customer churn taken from https://www.kaggle.com/blastchar/telco-customer-churn in order to predict churn using scikit-learn's LogisticRegression().

```
import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    data=pd.read_csv(file)

    #get rid of ID's
    data=data.iloc[:,1:]

    #turn categorical data to dummies
    data2=pd.get_dummies(data,columns=['gender', 'Partner', 'Dependents',
       'PhoneService', 'MultipleLines', 'InternetService', 'OnlineSecurity',
       'OnlineBackup', 'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport', 'StreamingTV',
       'StreamingMovies', 'Contract','PaperlessBilling', 'PaymentMethod'])

    #Some cleaning and adjustment
    data2["TotalCharges"].replace('[^0-9.]',np.nan,inplace=True,regex=True)
    data2["Churn"].replace(('Yes','No'),(1,0),inplace=True)
    data2=data2.dropna()

    #assign features and target 
    X = data2[data2.columns[:-1]] # Features
    y = data2.Churn # Target variable

    scores=cross_val_score(LogisticRegression(), X, y, cv=10) 
    print(scores)
```

However this prints only scores of 1, I also tried to use shuffling with Shuffle split.Why my data is overfitting ,or is there any other problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data cleaning you forgot to remove the target column from your training data.

After getting dummies, `'Churn'` is not the last column anymore, `data2.columns[:-1]` leaves it inside the training set, and your model ends up learning from it.

Comment: This answer is absolutely right. But, what you were experiencing was not overfitting. Overfitting is when your training errors goes down at the expanse of your validation score, which is the approximation of the generalization power of your model. In your case, you just had too much info to make the prediction, but the model learned correctly how to predict on the validation set.

Comment: Actually this is what is called data leakage.